# Bootstrap: add spacing between columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I am new to bootstrap and am trying to figure out how to put spacing in between boxes in second `row-fluid` in a `container-fluid`. I am trying to use the `class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 item col-xs-12"` so my page will have three columns on larger screens, two columns on tablets, and one column on mobile devices.

I have developed the following bootply to demonstrate where I am getting stuck:

[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/yLm3L3ymkT)

This example has two rows and I want to add spacing betwen the col1, col2, col3 boxes.

I have tried adding a `margin-left= 4px;` to the `#col1` css but that seems to make the col3 get stuck below col1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to suggest one more solution.

Make additional div inside each #col1:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="start" class="span12">

        Line1<br>
        Line2<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div calss="row-fluid">
    <div class="col1 col-lg-4 col-md-6 item col-xs-12"><div class="col-inside"> Col1 </div></div>
    <div class="col1 col-lg-4 col-md-6 item col-xs-12"><div class="col-inside"> Col2 </div></div>
    <div class="col1 col-lg-4 col-md-6 item col-xs-12"><div class="col-inside"> Col3 </div></div>
  </div>
```

and add col1's childs styles to your css

```
#start {
  background-color: #f1f2f6;
  margin-bottom:8px;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: #f1f2f6;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.col-inside {
  border: solid 2px #000000;

}
.col1:first-child {
  padding: 0 4px 0 0;
}
.col1:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0 4px;
}
.col1:last-child {
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
}
```

It makes right margin 4px and 0px for left one in first column, left margin 4px in last column, and right and left margins 4px in middle column only if there are 3 columns.
Here is [bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/rnzwyQ3J0i#)

Comment: Ids should be unique, in a html page. If you want to apply some css rules to more than one elements you have to use classes.

Comment: Surely you're right. Crazy mess. But question was about gaps. I Have changed code.

Answer (score 1):

You mean [offsetting collumns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) ???

You can do it using the col-md-offset-* class. For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to offset a number of columns, rather 4px.  I'm not sure if i need to change something in the `bootstrap.css` or if its somthing i need to write my own css for.

Comment: I believe the offset classes do a margin-left to the elements, so you could do something similar to this. Perhaps create a class .myOffset { margin-left: 4px; } and asign it to the elements, or you can specify the margin-left from the offset class by doing something like this #anId .col-md-offset-4{ margin-left: 4px; }

Comment: basicly you can overwrite the bootstrap css by your own

Comment: Thanks,  I will look try to see if i can make it work.